# Why do you need to regenerate Laravel session after login?

Tags: laravel-authentication, laravel-10, laravel-session, php-8.2

So in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users) it says that we "should regenerate the user's session to prevent session fixation"

But when I `Auth::login($user)` I see that session updates to a different id already.

```
// AuthController
public function __invoke() {
    // session()->getId(): a111
    Auth::login($user);
    // sesId: a222
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    // sesId: a333
}
//
```

So in my understanding Laravel's `login()` already regenerate session id. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: CAPEC is a good source if you want to learn more about different kinds of attacks and how they can be conducted: [Session fixation](https://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/61.html)

Answer (score 0):

To escape the threats arising from session fixation attacks. A session fixation attack occurs when an attacker or a hacker tricks your users into using a session the hacker already has control over. The hacker might have acquired the session ID through a cross site scripting attack or through a **click bait**. Once the user clicks on the click bait link then the attacker gains access to the **user's session ID** which is usually embedded in the request the browser sends to the server. That is why you need to change the session state by regeneration a new session ID every time a user logs in.

Protecting the session is very important as sensitive info is usually stored in the session variable such as **usernames, emails etc**. A hacker can use those to hack into your credit card and other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the code and found out that indeed the session id is already regenerated with `auth()->login($user)`, but `session()->regenerate()` also regenerates the CSRF token.